# Python PyNER library doesn't give any output

Tags: python, named-entity-recognition

I want to use pyNER library in order to extract names from a sentence.

I have installed ner on my ubuntu machine, then I have written the following script for the test.

```
>>> import ner
>>> tagger = ner.HttpNER(host='localhost', port=80)
>>> tagger.json_entities("Alice went to the Museum of Natural History.")
```

Normally, I have to get this output:

```
'{"ORGANIZATION": ["Museum of Natural History"], "PERSON": ["Alice"]}'
```

But I get nothing:

```
{}
```

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is an issue (https://github.com/dat/pyner/issues/2)

To get it working, you have to specify the output format (slashTags):

```
tagger = ner.SocketNER(host='localhost',port=80, output_format='slashTags')
```

Also, I would consider using another port besides 80 as that is usually reserved for web traffic.

Also if that doesn't work, use **SocketNER** instead of **HttpNER** and follow the instructions per NER's FAQ

http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.shtml#cc

```
cp stanford-ner.jar stanford-ner-with-classifier.jar 
jar -uf stanford-ner-with-classifier.jar classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz 
java -mx500m -cp stanford-ner-with-classifier.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERServer -port 9191 -loadClassifier classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz &
```

And then in your python script

```
import ner
tagger = ner.SocketNER(host='localhost',port=9191, output_format='slashTags')
print tagger.get_entities("University of California is located in California, United States")
```

Comment: Am also facing the same issue. So i executed every step. After the last step i got an error `Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected`

Comment: what is this port number? how to choose it?
I am getting error '[WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'